# How to get ActionResult<T> in unit tests with xUnit

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I would like to test controllers.

Here is one of them:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<AccountTypeDTO>> GetAccountTypeById(string id)
{
    try
    {
        //Some stuffs
        return Ok(accountTypeDTO);
    }
    catch
    {            
        //Some stuffs
        return Ok(accountTypeDTO);
    }
}
```

In the test class, how to get the `AccountTypeDTO` returned by the method?

I have tried something like that but without success:

```
var returnedDTO = _accountTypesController.GetAccountTypeById(createdId).Result as OkObjectResult;
```

**EDIT:**

The following works:

```
AccountTypeDTO returnedDTO =(AccountTypeDTO)((OkObjectResult)_accountTypesController.GetAccountTypeById(createdId).Result.Result).Value;
```

but probably a little bit messy.

Another option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically what you already found, but instead of hard casting you should use assert methods like `Assert.IsType<T>()`.

Example:

```
// Act
var result = await _accountTypesController.GetAccountTypeById(createdId);

// Assert
var actionResult = Assert.IsType<ActionResult<AccountTypeDTO>>(result);
var okObjectResult = Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(actionResult.Result);
var returnValue = Assert.IsType<AccountTypeDTO>(okObjectResult.Value);
```

Official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#test-actionresultt